# stat_summary bar chart labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can someone please help me understand how to place a mean label slightly ABOVE the bar chart using stat_summary in ggplot2? Here is my code:

```
#Create data frame
industry = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2) 
choice = c(1,2,3,2,1,4,5,3,5,5) 
df =data.frame(industry,choice)

#Define data to plot
line <- ggplot(df, aes(industry, choice)) 

#Plot data, bar chart
test <- line + 
  theme_classic() + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", width=0.4, aes(group = 1)) +    
  labs(x = "product", y = "firm size preference") +  
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("pizza","headphones")) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=12)) 
test + 
  ggtitle(label =  "FIGURE 1", subtitle = "FIRM SIZE PREFERENCE") +   
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12), 
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 10)
  )
```

Comment: `+ stat_summary(aes(label = stat(y)), geom = "text", fun.y = "mean", vjust = -1)`

Comment: Thanks @Axeman I did see that other post, but couldn't get it to fit my code.  BTW, your recommended code in the above line produced the following error: Error in stat(y) : could not find function "stat"

Comment: Update your ggplot2, or replace stat(y) with ..y..

Comment: that didn't work either.  thanks for the help, though.

Comment: It is working just fine over here, I tested the code. You'll have to be more specific than "that didn't work". (In the future, if you have tried to use a post that already answers your question, you should indicate why that answer is not working for you. Otherwise you just get the same answer again.)